# Не получается настроить proxy_pass с параметром

Tags: nginx

Имеется поддомен `s.` и есть сервер ExpressJS. Хочу настроить nginx так, чтобы он слушал запросы на `s.example.com/2t9HCYA`, но к прокси запрос передавал как `example.com/s/2t9HCYA`. Пробовал два варианта:

1) `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/s$1;` - к прокси серверу приходит просто `/s`

2) Также к прокси приходит только `/s`:

```
rewrite ^ /s$1 break;
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
```

Хотя если передать значение `$1` через `proxy_set_header`, то в заголовках запроса `2t9HCYA` будет присутствовать. Почему эта переменная напрочь игнорируется nginx и как заставить её работать?

Comment: Посмотрел на сервер. Ну так откуда же возьмётся `$1` если нигде нет регулярки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если оставлять ваш `try_files` и именованый `location`, тогда нужно правильно использовать `rewrite`:

```
location @express {
    rewrite ^(.+) /s$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    # другие proxy_* директивы
}
```

А можно переписать так:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /s$uri;
}

location /s/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/s/;
    # другие proxy_* директивы
}
```

Comment: Так тоже пробовал. Из-за этого возникает ошибка: `[emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block`

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin о, покажите тогда весь блок

Comment: Пожалуйста: https://pastebin.com/e2txh6RT

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Обновил ответ

Comment: Всё равно почему-то к express приходит `/s/` и при этом `s.example.com/2t9HCYA` превращается просто в `s.example.com`

Comment: Первый вариант железобетонный и не может не работать.

Comment: Да, вы правы, всё работает, спасибо. Нужно было тестировать через консоль, а не через браузер, ибо последний закешировал всё и показывал мне старый ответ.